# Do two congruent right triangles always make an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry

two right triangles both have equal hypotenuses and equal lengths of base (2m) are joined to make one triangle. The base of the new triangle is now 4 m (2m + 2m). what is the perimeter of the new triangle?

A math teacher solved this by assuming that the new triangle is equilateral so 30-60-90 special right triangle principle can be used. Is this assumption true?

Comment: It is not.  If the legs are equal $(2\times 2)$ they will each be $45^\circ - 45^\circ - 90^\circ$ triangles.  And when joined will form a $45^\circ - 45^\circ - 90^\circ$ triangle.

Comment: These are FAKE NEWS to discredit our category! (just kidding :)

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't. Consider a triangle with side lengths $3, 4$ and $5$. This is a right triangle, but if we glue two copies of them together along the shortest edge, we will get a triangle with lengths $5, 5$ and $8$, which is obviously not equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

That's false. Let $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ be two isosceles right triangles (with respect to $B$ and $E$ respectively) such that $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle DEF$ and let $\ell>0$ be such that $|AB|=|BC|=\ell=|DE|=|EF|$, then $|AC|=|DF|=\ell \sqrt{2}$. Then the base of the "new triangle $\triangle BAF$" is $|BF|=2\ell$ but $|BA|=|AF|=\ell\sqrt{2}$. Thus $\triangle BAF$ is equilateral if and only if $$2\ell=\ell\sqrt{2} \iff \ell(2-\sqrt{2})=0 \iff \ell =0 \: \vee \: 2=\sqrt{2},$$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the original question: "The front section of a tent is shaped from two right triangles each of which has equal legs. If the width of the tent is 4 m, find the perimeter of that section." The teacher solved it by considering it as equilateral triangle and results in perimeter of 12 m. So is this correct?

Comment: @jonforall No, your teacher is super wrong. The correct answer, assuming "two right triangles each of which has equal legs" means that the two right triangles are isoceles, should be $4 + 2\sqrt{8}$ which is approximately $9.66$.

If the two right trangles are not isoceles, I don't think there's enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: My answer is the perimeter = 4 + 4 root 2 m. ? (not my teacher, but my younger brother's teacher)

Comment: @jonforall $4 + 4\sqrt{2} = 4 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \sqrt{2} = 4 + 2 \cdot \sqrt{4} \cdot \sqrt{2} = 4 + 2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \cdot 4} = 4 + 2\sqrt{8}$. That is, it's the same answer as mine.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: You're very welcome.